# How to create fragment dynamically in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

when we use fragment in viewpager, we alway add fragment when adapter call the constructor.so when the actvitiy call onCreate(), all the fragment would construct and call onCreate() at the same time.
but I want to construct the fragment when we slide in.what should I do?
For example:
I have 4 fragment: fragment1, fragmeng2, fragment3, fragment4.
at first, the viewpager would create fragment1, and when we slide into next fragment(right slip), the viewpager would create fragment2, and the fragment2 would call it onCreate().
How can I make it?

Thanks a lot for your help,so sorry about my pool English and I don't know have I explain the problem clarify.
Thanks again.

Comment: just return your `Fragment` in `getItem` method (i assume you are using `FragmentPagerAdapter`)

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the creation of the fragment to the getItem() method in your adapter and return the newly created fragment.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be a bit lacking but I'm sure someone can complete it.
So what you can do is just create one fragment in the onCreate() of the activity. Implement the function onScrollChanged() and try to keep track there with getScrollX() where the user is exactly is in relation to the screen and just make some "if" statements that removes/adds the fragments as you are scrolling to the side.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, viewpager actually loads the fragments at once (onCreate and onResume). If your intention is to do something before the next page is displayed, this link might give you an alternate way of doing this.

https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/viewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code/

Comment: I just want to call onCreate() when the fragment is displayed.So I can request data dynamically.